# Multiple transitional element on same wpf doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, transitional

Am working on C# wpf application where am using Transitionals framework for animations (https://transitionals.codeplex.com/)

I have 3 different transition elements on same wpf application. Each have unique name, also 2 has same effects whereas one has different effect, but on running the application all three gives same effect, changing randomly between those 2 effects (fade and Rotate).

Here is my XAML code :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3">
     <transc:TransitionElement x:Name="livecheck" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="180 10 250 15" Width="140">
                <transc:TransitionElement.TransitionSelector>
                    <trans:RandomTransitionSelector>
                        <transt:FadeTransition/>
                    </trans:RandomTransitionSelector>
                </transc:TransitionElement.TransitionSelector>
            </transc:TransitionElement>
            <transc:TransitionElement x:Name="formatcheck" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="360 10 20 15" Width="160">
                <transc:TransitionElement.TransitionSelector>
                    <trans:RandomTransitionSelector>
                        <transt:FadeTransition/>
                    </trans:RandomTransitionSelector>
                </transc:TransitionElement.TransitionSelector>
    </transc:TransitionElement>
 </Grid>


        <Grid Margin="410,5,12,15" Grid.Row="4">
            <transc:TransitionElement x:Name="TransitionBox" Height="66" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="105">
                <transc:TransitionElement.TransitionSelector>
                    <trans:RandomTransitionSelector>
                        <transt:RotateTransition Angle="45" />
                    </trans:RandomTransitionSelector>
                </transc:TransitionElement.TransitionSelector>
            </transc:TransitionElement>
        </Grid>
```